# Running make under windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, makefile, gnu-make

I want to execute the command `make all` under my windows machine. For this I installed [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Furthermore, I want to compile node library [talib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/talib).

However, when running `make all`, I get:

```
C:\Users\User\nodeWorkspace\TestProject\node_modules\node-talib-master>make all
make: *** No Rule, to create »all«.  End.
```

When trying the following I get:

```
C:\Users\User\nodeWorkspace\TestProject\node_modules\node-talib-master>make all
make: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4227d3)
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

The `MakeFile` looks like that:

```
# Alternate way of building node-talib module
# Similar results can be achieved with npm

all:
    @cd ./src/lib && node build.js && cd ../../ && node-gyp configure && node-gyp build
    @echo
    @echo build complete

clean:
    @rm -rf build/* && cd ./src/lib && node clean.js && cd ../../
    @echo
    @echo clean complete
```

Comment: Well what's in the Makefile?

Comment: `C:\Users\User\nodeWorkspace\TestProject\node_modules\talib>make all` I think you're just in the wrong dir

Comment: @Pointy pls have a look at my update!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/375029/make-interrupt-exception-caught